# Combinatorics involving a matrix

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
How many possibilities are there to arrange $\{1,...2n$}$ in two columns such that:
in every row and every column the numbers increase.

Actually, this is part (c) in the question.

In part (a) I was asked to calculate the number of possibilities with only the demand for rows, while in part (b) I was asked to calculate the possiblities with only the demand for columns.

The answers are:
(a) $(2n)! \over 2^n $
(b) $(2n)! \over n!n!$

I guess it can be used for the third part I'm struggeling with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider how you can place the numbers $\{1,2,...,2n\}$ into the columns, starting with $1$ and proceeding from there. We create a string of $X$'s and $Y$'s, which, when read from the beginning indicate where to place the next number. $X$ means place the number in the left column, $Y$ says place the number in the right column. Now, note that all of the strings of $X$'s and $Y$'s that are legal are the [Dyck Words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_word#Applications_in_combinatorics) of length $2n$. So, we see that the number of ways of placing the $2n$ numbers is the $n$th Catalan number, $\frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n}$.

Or, if you know the hooklength formula, you can count these as Young tableaux.